# Bootstrap col height equals to row height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tyring to avoid col height's equality to row height in Bootstrap. Here is the script:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
   <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
</div>
```

The col-sm-9 column's content is more than col-sm-3, so its height is bigger than col-sm-3's. But col-sm-3's height increases with col-sm-9. How can I avoid it and set auto height according to content.

Thanks.

Comment: `<div class="row align-items-start">`

Comment: Thank you, solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in the comments by [Paulie_d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d).

```
<div class="row align-items-start"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm using react-bootstrap and when I did the above it made the col widths non-responsive.  Doing `<Row  style = {{alignItems:"flex-start"}}>` worked for me.